# For Admin, Manager i want show every record , for normal user I want show records created by that particular user only

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

How to filter records for tree view based on logged in user. For Admin, Manager i want show every record , for normal user I want show records created by that particular user only.

Below code sample I tried

For manager `uid=12`

For admin `uid=1`

```
 <field name="domain">[('|',('create_uid','=',uid),('|',(uid,'=','1'),(uid,'=','12')))]</field>
```

Above code sample is throwing error

> "ValueError: Invalid leaf ['|', ['create_uid', '=', 1], ['|', [1, '=',
>   '1'], [1, '=', '12']]]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row-level access rules are defined in the ir.rule model and can be created by adding a corresponding xml file to the module. The file is usually stored under security/ folder in your module directory.

For example I've taken `user.purchase.records` as the model

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="user_purchase_record_rule" model="ir.rule">
      <field name="name">Records created by current user only</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="model_user_purchase_records"/>
      <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid','=',user.id)]</field>
      <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Finally add this file path in your manifest.py file.

Answer (score 0):

A domain it's composed by 3 elements, `(field_in_your_model, operator, value)`, I don't know if you are working with a known model or it's your definition, but you got that error because *uid* it's a reserved word for odoo, not a field in a model.
And the best approach for your requirement its make rules, for your groups of users, something like *sale groups*:

Rule for *Sale / User: Own Documents Only*:

`['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]`

I hop this answer can be helpful you.